# I cannot get ForEach for stream to print a list

Tags: java, foreach, stream, void

I am wondering why forEach wont work for my program. I want to print each of the element from the List.

Error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to List
                                                                                        .forEach(i -> System.out.println(i + " "));

```
List <Integer> evenNumList = Arrays.asList(valuesArray)
                                                .stream()
                                                .filter(x -> (x % 2 == 0))
                                                .forEach(i -> `System.out.println(i + " "));`
```

I am confused as why the above does not work but the following works:

```
List <Integer> number = Arrays.asList(2,3,4,5);
        number.stream().map(x->(x*x)).forEach(y->System.out.println(y));
```

Comment: forEach's return type is void. So, you cannot assign the result (there is none) to a variable (`evenNumList`). Remove the assignment

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your code is not working is because you're trying to assign the result of forEach to the list, which in your case is void. Because forEach is going to run and print the elements and not return anything, you get the error.

```
Arrays.asList(valuesArray).stream().filter(x -> (x % 2 == 0)).forEach(i -> `System.out.println(i + " "));`
```

If you modify your code and remove the assignment operation, the error should go away.

Edit as the question was updated.

The code below works because;

```
List <Integer> number = Arrays.asList(2,3,4,5); number.stream().map(x->(x*x)).forEach(y->System.out.println(y));
```

Here in the first line you're assigning the values to the list.

```
List <Integer> number = Arrays.asList(2,3,4,5);
```

Here in the second line, now that the list already has values, you're going to just iterate over each of them and print.

```
number.stream().map(x->(x*x)).forEach(y->System.out.println(y));
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by assigning the result of forEach to the list. My understanding is i want to print out all the elements in the List which each element is denoted as i.

Comment: I've updated the answer as you updated the question after I answered the initial question. Your understanding of forEach is correct that it should iterate over each element and print, but at the same time, you've preceeded it with "List<Integer> evenNumList = " which means you're trying to assign something to the evenNumList, which is void as you're running a forEach statement to print elements, thus you get the error.

Comment: What you are wanting, and what you are doing are not the same thing.   What you are doing (i.e. what you wrote!) is assigning something to `evenNumList` but there is nothing to assign because the `forEach` method doesn't return anything.

Comment: Note: it doesn't help if you change the code in your question.  (How can someone answer a question that keeps changing?)

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
List <Integer> evenNumList = ...
```

and then

```
  .forEach(i -> `System.out.println(i + " "));`
```

You want to assign the "result" of that stream operation to a List. `forEach()` just iterates your stream, which is simply not what you want. Just go:

```
..filter(x -> (x % 2 == 0)).collect(Collectors.asList());
```

That will *collect* all the items you want. Then **afterwards**, simply go

```
System.out.println(evenNumList);
```

for example!

And minor note: dont add the type to the variable. Simply call it `evenNumbers` for example.